# How can we remove rows between multiple dataframe that shared a commun words in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, apply, cbind

I have 36 dataframes (divided in two groups H and E; 18 for each). All my dataframes carry a column with multiple words called 'AA'. I would like to remove all the words in H that exists in E and keep only the words unshared between H or E.

Do you have any idea of how I could do it ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What do you mean by group? Two lists with 18 data frames each? Or they're not grouped at all, but for you the 36 data frames represent 2 groups?

And you mean "remove all rows in H..." right?

Comment: Two lists of 18 data frames, yes ! No, I would like to remove all rows in H and E that shared a commun words like "chocolate" in a colmun called 'AA' ('AA' is present in all my dataframes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I tried to simulate your environment. I have a list `my_dfs` with 4 data frames, `H1`, `H2`, `E1`, `E2`, belonging to two groups, `H` and `E`, as you can imagine. See the R code below.

```
H1 <- data.frame(Name = c('Marcel', 'Bob', 'John'),
                 AA = c('Soccer', 'Swimming', 'Baseball'))

H2 <- data.frame(Age = c('20', '41', '22'),
                 AA = c('something', 'something4', 'something5'))

E1 <- data.frame(Age = c('20', '41', '22'),
                 AA = c('something', 'something2', 'something3'))
E2 <- data.frame(Age = c('20', '41', '22'),
                 AA = c('Basketball', 'Voleyball', 'Baseball'))

my_dfs <- list(H1, H2, E1, E2)
```

There are some words in the column `AA` that are common among the 4 data frames and you would like to remove the rows in each data frame that contain a word in `AA` that is also in the `AA` column of the others.

```
purrr::map(seq_along(my_dfs),
           ~ dplyr::anti_join(my_dfs[[.x]],
                              dplyr::bind_rows(my_dfs[-.x]),
                              by = 'AA'))
```

The code above should solve your problem.

Comment: The example works well but when I tried it on my dfs, I have this error :
Error in UseMethod("anti_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'anti_join' applied to an object of class "character"